# How top stop images overlapping other content

Tags: html, css, image, overlap

When reducing screen size the images overlap the footer instead of pushing it further down the page. Images are all 720x1280. However, on a bigger screen the images fall in correctly.

How can I resolve this? Completely new in HTML and CSS so please bear with me.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <div class="container-md">
                <div id="topbar"> <!--Search div-->
                    <form method="get" class="input-group">
                        <img src="/icons/search-white.svg" alt="Search">                    
                        <input  id="search-field" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                    </form>
                    <div id="logo">
                        <img src="/icons/globe-white.svg" alt="Logo">
                    </div>                
                    <div id="menu">
                        <nav class="d-none d-md-block">
                            <a href="destinations_gallery.html">Destinations</a>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-light">Sign in</a>
                        </nav>
                        <img class="d-md-none" src="/icons/three-bars-white.svg" alt="Menu">
                    </div>                             
                    
                </div>                
                <div class="destinations"> <!--images div-->
                    
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Eiffel Tower, Paris" src="/images/destinations/paris.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                              <strong>Paris</strong>
                              <div class="country">France</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Golden Gate Bridge, San Francisco" src="/images/destinations/san-francisco.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                              <strong>San Francisco</strong>
                              <div class="country">United States</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Sydney Opera House, Sydney" src="/images/destinations/sydney.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                              <strong>Sydney</strong>
                              <div class="country">Australia</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Sensō-ji, Tokyo" src="/images/destinations/tokyo.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                              <strong>Tokyo</strong>
                              <div class="country">Japan</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Eiffel Tower, Paris" src="/images/destinations/paris.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                              <strong>Paris</strong>
                              <div class="country">France</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Eiffel Tower, Paris" src="/images/destinations/paris.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                              <strong>Paris</strong>
                              <div class="country">France</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Eiffel Tower, Paris" src="/images/destinations/paris.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                                <strong>Paris</strong>
                                <div class="country">France</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Eiffel Tower, Paris" src="/images/destinations/paris.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                                <strong>Paris</strong>
                                <div class="country">France</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Eiffel Tower, Paris" src="/images/destinations/paris.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                                <strong>Paris</strong>
                                <div class="country">France</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Eiffel Tower, Paris" src="/images/destinations/paris.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                                <strong>Paris</strong>
                                <div class="country">France</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Eiffel Tower, Paris" src="/images/destinations/paris.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                                <strong>Paris</strong>
                                <div class="country">France</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination">
                            <img alt="Eiffel Tower, Paris" src="/images/destinations/paris.jpg">
                            <div class="location">
                                <strong>Paris</strong>
                                <div class="country">France</div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                </div>                                            
                       
    
               
            </div>         
            

        </header>
    <footer>
        <div class="container-md">
            <div> <!--links div-->
                <h3>Links</h3>
                <nav>
                    <a href="">Home</a>
                    <a href="">Destinations</a>
                    <a href="">About</a>
                    <a href="">Contact</a>
                </nav>
            </div>        
            
            <div> <!--newsletter div-->
                <h3>Newsletter</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla euismod, nisl nec tincidunt dapibus, magna libero fermentum augu. </p>
            <form class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                Subscribe
                <img src="/icons/arrow-right-white.svg" alt="arrow">
                </button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
                    

    </footer>    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

gallery.css:

```
.destinations {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    gap: 10px;    
    padding: 20px;
        
}
.destination {
    position: relative;       
}
#destinations {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.destination .location strong {
    font-family: "Dancing Script";
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.destination .location .country {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 14px;
}
.destination .location {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.destination img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    object-fit: cover;
       
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {    
    
    .destinations {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
    .destinations img {
        max-height: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .destination {
        height: auto;
        
    }
    .destination img {
        max-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

header.css:

```
#topbar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;   
     
}
#logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    
}
#menu nav a {
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
}
header {
    background-image: url('/images/header.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    color: white;
    height: 100vh;    
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
header > .container-md {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%
}
header h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {    
    #menu img {
        display: none;
    } 
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #menu nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
#search-field {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

footer.css:

```
footer {
    background-color: #ffc107;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
  }
  footer nav a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {    
    footer > .container-md {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        gap: 20px;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `header` is set to `height:100vh;`, meaning it will always be as high as the viewport, but never higher. And since your images are inside `header`, they will be unable to make `header` higher even though the images themselves are pushing beyond that.